# User cannot modify field on which they have read/write permission.

Tags: permissions, permission-sets

I have a set of users who belong to a permission set that has read/edit access on certain custom fields on the Opportunity object. When those users attempt to modify any of these custom fields, they receive an error message stating the following:

> You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

I've looked for any validation rules that prevent these updates based on the user profile, but have found nothing that would prevent the update. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the permission sets are appropriately applied and the users have the right kind of licenses, this sounds like it's probably a role hierarchy issue.

Role hierarchies can prevent the users trying to modify the Opportunity from doing so. If this is happening, that means the user's position in the role hierarchy doesn't allow them to edit other people's Opportunities, even if they are associated with Accounts they own. You can modify these settings by going to Your Name > Setup > Manage Users > Roles and click the the user's role. There are two Opportunity Access radio buttons that look like this:

[image]

Comment: This got me half-way there. I ended up creating an Opportunity Sharing Rule so that users in the same role could modify other user's opportunities. Thanks for your help!